# Как получить выборку по времени SQL timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть поля `timestamp 2022-12-21 05:53:00` и мне надо сделать выборку при помощи `where` только по времени `05:53`

```
Select * from `time` where `time`.`time` = ...
```

Как это правильно сделать? Думал через hour и minute, но это не совсем удобно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: ```WHERE TIME(timespamp_column) = '05:53:00'```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, получилось.

```
select date_format(Time,'%H:%i') as HourAndMinutes from `Time`;
```